# How to use python3 to read some specific columns of .xlsx files, sort them by time and put them into new row?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xlsx

I have a .xlsx data likes this.

```
NAME    a           b           c ...
2012    1246108359  190153864   NA ...
2013    1089521299  181339787   -122350575 ...
2015    2092545545  648831005   -69981000 ...
2014    802730996   435162019   -69644809 ...
2017    1681536957  690355938   -1210327000 ...
2016    1149898973  491972036   -226538000 ...
```

First, I want to extract every column and sort them by time.
And then, put them into a new row.
How can I do this?

It shall be like this.

```
2012    a   1246108359
2013    a   1089521299
2014    a   802730996
2015    a   2092545545
2016    a   1149898973
2017    a   1681536957
2012    b   190153864
2013    b   181339787
2014    b   435162019
2015    b   648831005
2016    b   491972036
2017    b   690355938
 ...   ...  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use melt to do this

firs sort values

```
df.sort_values('NAME', inplace=True)

df.melt(id_vars='NAME', value_vars=df.columns[1:])
```

you can use the params `value_name` and `var_name` to change the column names